Questions on the Weierstraß-Approximation
The Theorem  of Stone-Weierstraß tells us that the polynomials are uniformly dense in the continuous functions on a compact interval.
So my first question is: Given $f \in C([a,b])$, does this Theorem mean, that there is a sequence $a_n$ such that $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n $ ?
I think the answer is no, because this would mean, that $f$ is analytic and therefore differentiable. This would then imply that every continuous function is differentiable, what is not true.
Second question: If i want to approximate a continuous function by a sequence of polynomials, then each polynomial in the sequence might have totally different coefficients?

For the first question: There's no reason to believe that an approximating sequence converges, is there? For the second question: Doesn't the sequence $f_k(x) = (1+\frac1k)x$ approximate the polynomial $f(x) = x$ (say, on $[0,1]$)?

You're right about your first point. Generally, the sequence is of the form $p_n(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{k_j} a_{n, j}x^j$ which is a massive difference from what you wrote in your first question. Indeed, the coefficients might or might not be the same for every $n$ (see @MPW 's answer)
